# A 5-feet DEM - what does it mean?

Tags: qgis, dem

When it says that a particular DEM is say "5-feet DEM" - does it mean that:

1. The distance between two points when elevation was actually measured (or source data before interpolation) is at minimum 5 feet?

***or***

2. After interpolation, the distance between two adjacent points in the raster file is 5 feet?

Comment: Likely referring to spatial resolution of the raster.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_resolution

Comment: What does the metadata say?

Comment: Thanks. Looking at metadata was a good idea. It says the following.  <abstract>Bare-earth 5-foot DEM as 32-bit floating point raster format in ARCGIS GRID Raster format in compliance with USGS LIDAR Base Specifications such as: georeferencing information, delivered without overlap and with no edge artifacts or mismatched, “NODATA” value for void areas, bridges removed from the surface, etc.</abstract>
<purpose>This is a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) as a raster mosaic in ESRI float format 32bit representation on a 5ft grid created from the LiDAR collected for the  project ...</purpose>